# Avoiding message timeout in pynsq

Tags: python, nsq, pynsq

For example, I send a message to NSQ by issuing:

```
curl -d "test2" http://127.0.0.1:4151/pub?topic=hello
```

I've found that if message handler execution takes longer than 100 second, it will throw and this message will be timed out.

```
ERROR:nsq.client:[127.0.0.1:4150:hello:channel]      
ERROR: ConnectionClosedError('Stream is closed',)
WARNING:nsq.reader:[127.0.0.1:4150:hello:channel] connection closed
```

What can I do to avoid this timeout?

Here is my code:

```
def process_message(message):
    print(message)
    time.sleep(100)
    message.touch()
    return True

r_check = nsq.Reader(
     message_handler=process_message,
    nsqd_tcp_addresses=['127.0.0.1:4150'],
    topic='hello', channel='channel',
    lookupd_poll_interval=15,
    lookupd_connect_timeout=100000,
    lookupd_request_timeout=100000,
    max_tries=10
)

nsq.run()
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You should call `message.touch()` before processing the message in order to tell NSQD that you need more time to process the message.

There are two parameters in NSQD which control message timeouts: [max-msg-timeout and msg-timeout](https://nsq.io/components/nsqd.html#command-line-options).

Matt Reiferson explains how they work [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/nsq-users/xBQF1q4srUM/kX22TIoIs-QJ).